# Analogy between the exterior power and the power set

Tags: categorification, ct.category-theory, exterior-algebra, symmetric-monoidal-categories

The symmetric algebra of an object exists in every cocomplete $\otimes$-category. For the category of sets $\mathrm{Sym}(X)$ is the set of [multi-subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) of $X$.

The usual definition of the [exterior power](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70607/exterior-powers-in-tensor-categories) works in every cocomplete linear $\otimes$-category in which $2$ is invertible. But what about the non-linear case? Are there also "exterior powers" in $\otimes$-categories which are not linear? Of course the usual definition using alternating maps does not work. But isn't it striking that for the cartesian category of sets there is a quite natural candidate, namely the power set? Here are some analogies (here $P(X)$ denotes the power set of $X$ if $X$ is finite; in general it is the set of all finite subsets of $X$; $P_n(X)$ is the set of all subsets of $X$ with $n$ elements):

- $P(X) = \coprod_n P_n(X)$ and $\Lambda(M) = \oplus_n \Lambda^n(M)$
- $P(X \sqcup Y) = P(X) \times P(Y)$ and $\Lambda(M \oplus N) = \Lambda(M) \otimes \Lambda(N)$

It follows the "categorified [Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)":

- $P_n(X \sqcup Y) = \coprod_{p+q=n} P_q(X) \times P_q(Y)$ and $\Lambda^n(M \oplus N) = \oplus_{p+q=n} \Lambda^p(M) \otimes \Lambda^q(N)$
- $(P(X),\cup)$ is a commutative monoid and $(\Lambda(M),\wedge)$ is a graded-commutative algebra, i.e. commutative monoid object in the tensor category of graded modules equipped with twisted symmetry.
- If $M$ is free with (ordered) basis $X$, then $\Lambda(M)$ is free with basis $P(X)$, and $\Lambda^n(M)$ is free with basis $P_n(X)$. In particular, $\dim \Lambda^n(M)=\dim P_n(X)$.
- If $T$ is a commutative monoid, then homomorphisms $P(X) \to T$ correspond to maps $f : X \to T$ with $f(x)^2=f(x)$, and if $A$ is a graded-commutative algebra, then homomorphisms $\Lambda(M) \to A$ correspond to homomorphisms of modules $f : M \to A_1$ with $f(x)^2=0$ or rather $f(x)f(y)+f(y)f(x)=0$ in the context of $\otimes$-categories (so these conditions are not the same, but both use $f(x)^2$).

Therefore I would like to ask: Is there a notion of exterior algebra for certain cocomplete $\otimes$-categories, including categories of modules and the category of sets? In the latter case, do we get the power set?

Comment: By $P_n(X)$ do you mean the set of $n$-element subsets?  In that case your first identity holds only when $X$ is finite, while $\Lambda(M)$ makes sense for $M$ of any dimension and has the decomposition that you give.  Interesting question!

Comment: Ah sorry, I should write "finite power set" everywhere, i.e. the set of finite subsets.

Comment: Maybe the power set is more like a Clifford algebra.

Comment: @Tom: Interesting. But for which quadratic form? And I don't know how to categorify quadratic forms, and what they should be for sets. I can define and construct the Clifford algebra of an object $X$ in a cocomplete linear $\otimes$-category (for which $2$ is invertible) with respect to a symmetric bilinear form $b : X \otimes X \to 1$. It is the universal monoid object $\mathrm{Cl}(X,b)$ equipped with a morphism $i : X \to \mathrm{Cl}(X,b)$ such that $i(x)i(y) + i(y)i(x) = 2 b(x,y) 1$ (which is a sloppy way of writing an equation between two morphisms $X \otimes X \to \mathrm{Cl}(X,b)$).

Comment: To make the algebraic structure on $P(X)$ closer to that on $\Lambda(X)$, you can use the disjoint union rather than the union.  Then the last bullet looks a little better.  But note that the $\Lambda$ side of the last bullet doesn't make sense in arbitrary categories --- rather, it has something special to do with usual modules over a ring in which $2$ is invertible.

Comment: @Theo: Thanks, I've changed it. Do you mean the symmetric difference? Then in fact the universal property would be $x^2=1$ instead of $x^2=x$ (but still not $x^2=0$). But the monoid is still not graded. 

Comment: I wasn't really thinking of a quadratic form. I was just thinking that, like a Clifford algebra, the power set has a filtration such that the associated graded object is (like) an exterior algebra.

Comment: Meanwhile I've been able to formalize the analogy, using "$\pm$-enriched" categories.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Would it be possible for you to sketch in an answer how this formalization in terms of $\pm$-enriched categories works? Or give a link to someplace you've written it up?

Comment: @Dan Petersen: Thank you for your interest. I will write it up, but I cannot promise that this happens soon.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, did you get a chance to write it up?

Comment: Sketch: Consider $C_2\mathsf{-Set}$-enriched categories, i.e. each hom-set has a specified involution which we denote by $-$. If $R$ is a ring, $\mathsf{Mod}_R$ is an example. The category of sets is not an example but $C_2\mathsf{-Set}$ is an example, and we may use the free functor $\mathsf{Set}\to C_2\mathsf{-Set}$ etc. to reduce to the $C_2\mathsf{-Set}$-enriched case. Now, given a cocomplete tensor $C_2\mathsf{-Set}$-category, we call a map $\omega : X^{\otimes n} \to Y$ skew-symmetric if $\omega \circ \tau =  - \omega$ for any swap $\tau$. There is a universal example $\Lambda^n(X)$ etc.

Comment: My interpretation here is that the exterior power is to the powerset like the field with two elements $\mathbb{F}_2$ (with $1+1=0$) is to the boolean semiring, viꝫ. $\{0,1\}$ with logical and as multiplication and logical or as addition (so $1+1=1$): there is a similarity between the two structures in that they are semirings with two elements (a “semiring” or “rig” is a ring without subtraction), but they are not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To a set $X$ associate the free vector space $M(X)$ over $X$; conversely, for a vector space $M$ let $X$ be the index set of a basis of $M$. Then the analogy is just how one does exterior algebra in terms of a basis.

This fits into the way how representation theory for $GL(n)$ and for the symmetric group $S(n)$
are related to each other, both using Young projectors in interated tensor products of $\mathbb C^n$. This becomes more striking even if we take the direct limit for $n\to \infty$.
See books and papers by Yuri Neretin (in arXiv).

Edit: For modules $M$ over an algebra $A$, one could consider the corresponding algebra of dual numbers $A\circledS M$ (i.e., $A\oplus M$ with multiplication
$(a,m).(a',m') = (a.a', a.m' + m.a')$ and the Kaehler differentials over this algebra.
See 2.3 of [here](https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/%7Emichor/ncdg.pdf).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question is whether there is a general construction which specializes to both the exterior algebra and the power set, not whether you can relate the power set and the exterior algebra. 

Comment: I agree with Qiaochu. See also the fourth $\bullet$.

Comment: I cannot see any connection between the Edit and my question.

Comment: The algebra of Kaehler differentials of $A\circledS M$ generalizes the exterior algebra from vector spaces to modules over a commutative algebra, or even to bimodules over a non-commutative algebra.

Comment: And what are Kaehler differentials for non-linear tensor categories?